# SSL error in show video with chewie package flutter in android 7

Tags: android, flutter, ssl

I have problem to show video in chewie package in flutter,
in android 7 not showing video and get this error:

```js
Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:632)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:604)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x783416d0fac0: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:373)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1005)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x783416d0fac0: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:644)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:541)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:367)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       ... 6 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):       Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x783416d0fac0: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):           ... 22 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):           Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):               at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:429)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):               ... 20 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):           Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x783416d0fac0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):   error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:610 0x7834293ea540:0x00000001)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):   error:1000009a:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c:764 0x78343e00d76a:0x00000000)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):               at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):               at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 2859):               ... 20 more
E/flutter ( 2859): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)
E/flutter ( 2859):
```

this error just show in android 7 and another android not show this problem.

[image]

this picture show SSLl Test in [SSLLab](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html)

Comment: This is likely caused by the server requiring TLS properties which are not supported by the older client, like specific TLS protocols like TLS 1.3 or specific ciphers. Unfortunately - nothing is known about the target server. You might check [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) for the specific server. There you'll also find an estimate which Android versions are likely supported for access to the server.

Comment: thanks, i Test SSl in SSLLab that  suggested, can you review?

Comment: So in theory Android 7 should work. There might be special settings in your application though which is unknown. Also, the server sending a handshake failure is pretty generic, but can for example happen when client certificates are required for authentication but the client does not send one or the one sent is not trusted. Nothing is known about your application here either. Also, compare the environment you use with the failing to the working version, i.e. is this exactly the same network, same kind of internet access ... ? Too much unknown.